# Python Search File For Specific Word And Find Exact Match And Print Line

Tags: python-2.7

I wrote a script to print the lines containing a specific word from a bible txt file.The problem is i couldn't get the exact word with the line instead it prints all variations of the word.

For eg. if i search for "am" it prints sentences with words containing      "lame","name" etc.
Instead i want it to print only the sentences with "am" only

i.e, "I am your saviour", "Here I am" etc

Here is the code i use:

```
import re
text = raw_input("enter text to be searched:")

shakes = open("bible.txt", "r")

for line in shakes:
    if re.match('(.+)'  +text+  '(.+)', line):
        print line
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think if you, in the strings outside `text`, put spaces like this:

```
'(.+) ' + text + ' (.+)'
```

That would do the trick, if I correctly understand what is going on in the code.

Comment: Thanks SparklePony it worked.I'm a newbie and just starting out. Could you explain what is the difference in this code.

Comment: The difference in this code is it searches for sentences with the word "am" that have spaces around them. If you look carefully in the strings surrounding `text`, spaces were added, so basically that keeps it from finding "ham" because there is not a space in the front. I hope this answer makes sense.

Comment: Also, could you click the check mark next to this answer if you like it? When you do that it means you like the answer given. (And I get reputation.)

Comment: sory i'm new to stackoverflow and didn't know about the tick

Answer (score 1):

This is another approach to take to complete your task, it may be helpful although it doesn't follow your current approach very much.

The test.txt file I fed as input had four sentences:

```
This is a special cat. And this is a special dog. That's an average    cat. But better than that loud dog.
```

When you run the program, include the text file. In command line, that'd look something like:

```
python file.py test.txt
```

This is the accompanying file.py:

```
import fileinput

key = raw_input("Please enter the word you with to search for: ")
#print "You've selected: ", key, " as you're key-word."

with open('test.txt') as f:
    content = str(f.readlines())

#print "This is the CONTENT", content

list_of_sentences = content.split(".")
for sentence in list_of_sentences:
    words = sentence.split(" ")
    for word in words:
        if word == key:
            print sentence
```

For the keyword "cat", this returns:

```
That is a special cat
That's an average cat
```

(note the periods are no longer there).

Comment: How can i give the txt file "bible.txt" as input and assign the raw_input variable to key.Thanks

Comment: There are a couple approaches to this, for example either go line by line or get all the content at once. This version get's all the content at once. I've updated the example above that shows this.

Answer (score 0):

[re.findall](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) may be useful in this case:

```
print re.findall(r"([^.]*?" + text + "[^.]*\.)", shakes.read())
```

Or even without regex:

```
print [sentence + '.' for sentence in shakes.split('.') if text in sentence]
```

reading this text file:

```
I am your saviour. Here I am. Another sentence.
Second line. 
Last line. One more sentence. I am done.
```

both give same results:

```
['I am your saviour.', ' Here I am.', ' I am done.']
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but an error occurs                                                "Type error:Expected string or buffer"                                                               "Return _compile(pattern,flags).findall(strings)"